# MySQL: Exclude matches if criterion is met

Tags: mysql

I have a database with three tables: `recipes`, `ingredients` and `allergens`. There are many-to-many relationships between both `recipes` and `ingredients`, and `ingredients` and `allergens`. These relationships are solved using the intermediate tables `ingredient_in_recipe` and `allergen_in_ingredient`, which contain only the respective ids for recipes, ingredients and allergens.

Now, selecting all ingredients in a set of recipes is simple, for instance for the recipes with id = 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 like this:

```
SELECT i.* FROM ingredients AS i
    INNER JOIN ingredient_in_recipe AS ir ON i.id = ir.ingredient_id
    INNER JOIN recipes AS r ON ir.recipe_id = r.id
WHERE r.id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

Furthermore, it is easy to add more `INNER JOIN`s and `WHERE` clauses to remove certain ingredients from the resulting data set. However, when a recipe has an ingredient with a certain allergen, I want to remove *all* matched ingredients from the results for any recipe that has that allergen in it, since that recipe is no longer valid due to allergy. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: I think the general direction is to use NOT EXISTS on subqery which get all the ingredients for a recipe with an allergen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query gets "safe" recipes with no allergens:

```
SELECT ir.recipe_id
FROM ingredient_in_recipe ir LEFT JOIN
     allergens_in_ingredient ai
     ON ai.ingredient_id = i.id
WHERE ir.recipe_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
GROUP BY ir.recipe_id
HAVING MAX(ai.allergen_id IS NULL) IS NULL;
```

Note that you don't need the `recipes` table or the `ingredients` table to get the "safe" recipes.

You can then join this back to the ingredients to get safe recipes with their incredients:

```
SELECT i.*
FROM (SELECT ir.recipe_id
      FROM ingredient_in_recipe ir LEFT JOIN
           allergens_in_ingredient ai
           ON ai.ingredient_id = i.id
      WHERE ir.recipe_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
      GROUP BY ir.recipe_id
      HAVING MAX(ai.allergen_id IS NULL) IS NULL
     ) rsafe JOIN
     ingredient_in_recipe ir
     ON rsafe.recipe_id = ir.recipe_id JOIN
     ingredients i INNER JOIN
     ON i.id = ir.ingredient_id
ORDER BY i.recipe_id;
```

Comment: Ok, so I hacked a bit more at the "safe" recipes and ended up with the following, which seems to work. Does it look ok? `SELECT ir.recipe_id FROM mm_ingredient_in_recipe AS ir LEFT JOIN mm_allergen_in_ingredient AS ai ON ai.ingredient_id = ir.ingredient_id WHERE ir.recipe_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) GROUP BY ir.recipe_id HAVING NOT MAX(ai.allergen_id IN (1, 2, 3));`. As far as I can tell this removes all recipes in `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` that has either of the allergens with id `(1, 2, 3)` in them. The `HAVING MAX(ai.allergen_id IS NULL) IS NULL;` above did not seem to work properly.

Comment: I can confirm that the example in the previous comment works. When inserting it into the overall query, however, I get multiple results for the same items where it should not be. I have tried several `WHERE` clauses, but nothing fixes exactly that. My current query looks like this: `SELECT i.name, ir.quantity, ir.unit FROM(<INSERT QUERY FROM PREVIOUS COMMENT HERE>) AS rsafe INNER JOIN ingredient_in_recipe AS ir ON rsafe.recipe_id = ir.recipe_id INNER JOIN ingredients AS i ON i.id = ir.ingredient_id WHERE ir.recipe_id = rsafe.recipe_id ORDER BY i.id;`

Comment: @Krøllebølle . . . The `join` should be a `left join` as in the first query.  The logic is a bit different.  The version in your comment only checks for three allergens, whereas I thought the intention was to check for all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I ended up with. I did not state it clearly in the question, but it is desirable to remove any recipe that has any ingredient that contains an allergen from a list. In the below, it is searched in all recipes and any recipe that contains allergen with id 1, 2 or 4. Since I did not need any data from the `recipe` table, it is left out of the last part of the query.

```
SELECT i.*, ir.*
FROM(SELECT ir.recipe_id
    FROM ingredient_in_recipe AS ir LEFT JOIN 
        allergen_in_ingredient AS ai ON ai.ingredient_id = ir.ingredient_id
    GROUP BY ir.recipe_id
    HAVING NOT MAX(ai.allergen_id IN (1, 2, 14))
    ) AS rsafe LEFT JOIN
        ingredient_in_recipe AS ir ON rsafe.recipe_id = ir.recipe_id INNER JOIN
        ingredients AS i on i.id = ir.ingredient_id
ORDER BY i.id;
```